# How to make the labels in different color?

Tags: neo4j

[image]

Please see the graph below. They should be very colorful!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to manually assign the colours in Neo4j Browser. This is pretty straightforward to do:

- Select the Node Label you wish to set a colour to (you will find the node labels at the top of the window when you bring back some results
- You will see a colour selector appears at the bottom of the window, choose your colour, and all nodes of that label will be set to that colour

Details here: https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-browser/#browser-styling

Comment: I used it before, and it was automatically assigned with different colors. Has this changed in recent releases?

Comment: I believe they have always been grey to start off with. However, what you may have experienced is that you initially coloured the nodes, and then in subsequent databases, you have used the same node labels - the colours will remain for the same labels, even if different databases are in use

Comment: @Lju There are only 11 color selections. My labels are much more than 11. How to deal with that?